# Multiple Joins using Criteria builder

Tags: java, jpa, criteria, hibernate-criteria, criteriaquery

Trying to build the critaria for the below query

```
Select a.x,c.y from A a
JOIN B b on a.a = b.a
JOIN C c on b.c = c.c
JOIN D d on c.d = d.d
```

Tried with below Criteria

```
Root<A> root = criteriaQuery.from(A);
Join<A, B> join1 = root.join(“b”);
Join<B, C> join2 = join1.join(“b”);
Join<C, D> join3 = join2.join(“c”)
```

But i was not getting expected results, any suggestions

Comment: What are the results you are getting? Note that you are showing us code for only part of the query, not the selection criteria, and we can only guess that the join1 and join2 methods are cut and paste errors that should read join1.join("b") and join2.join("c").

Comment: yeah, missed to add join i have updated it.

Comment: result that i'm getting is it is trying find the table name like B_C since we are trying to join join1(which is not a root) with table C, which is not available

Comment: What is trying to find a B_C table exactly? What is the relationship on A.b, and why would join1 (B) have a "b" relationship to C? Maybe show your entities and their mappings as it sounds like you are talking about a relation table on a M:M mapping